EF Core navigation properties to both a collection and a specific item in the collection
I have a main EF entity class which has a navigation property to a collection of another EF entity class in an one-to-many relationship. This second entity has a DateCreated property and a navigation reference back to the main class in a one-to-one relationshipenter code here.
For performance reasons I want to add another navigation property in the main class to the the most recent related entry in the class collection but am hitting lots of issues around foreign keys.
public class MainClass
{
   public virtual List<OtherClass> OtherClasses { get; set;}
   public virtual OtherClass LatestOtherClass { get; set; }
}

public class OtherClass
{
   public virtual MainClass { get; set;}
   public virtual DateTime DateCreated { get; set;}
}

The error I am getting  is 'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation of 'MainClass.LatestOtherClass' of type 'OtherClass'.
It is suggesting I manually configure the relationship but I have been unable to find a way to successfully do this so far without causing DbContext errors or breaking the relationship in the opposite direction.
Is this possible and if so how do I configure this?
This is against a Postgresql db if that is of any consequence.

Is your list of related entries lazily loaded ? If it's loaded eagerly you could just do list[list.length -1] to get the latest (assuming you have guarantees that the latest date created timestamp always correlates to the latest ID)

Lengthy story but we need to do this for performance reasons as the eager loading is too slow for our purposes.

I see, well I don't think there's a nice looking way to achieve this. Maybe this could help you, but it may be worthwhile to rethink your data model or the way you use the data. Whether you're loading a single related record or a set of such related records will have more or less the same overhead, unless the "many" in the relationship are of high cardinality
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66181846/entity-framework-core-one-to-many-but-parent-also-has-navigation-property-to-a

Indeed a schema, and overall architecture rethink is probably needed due to the volume of data but it is legacy code with a deadline looming so need to work with what is there.

If youre doig this for some historical audit purpose, and there is really only one OtherClass per MainClass, but the other records are previous then-valid iterations (like your residence address; last year was uni, this year the suburbs..) you can look at temporal tables and have SQLS maintain the history for you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/temporal-tables

I think below code will help to fix your problem.
public class MainClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Primary Key for EF

    public virtual List<OtherClass> OtherClasses { get; set; }

    public int? LatestOtherClassId { get; set; } // Foreign Key to OtherClass
    public virtual OtherClass LatestOtherClass { get; set; }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Primary Key for EF

    public int MainClassId { get; set; } // Foreign Key to MainClass
    public virtual MainClass MainClass { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MainClass> MainClasses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OtherClass> OtherClasses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Configure one-to-many relationship between MainClass and OtherClass
        modelBuilder.Entity<MainClass>()
            .HasMany(m => m.OtherClasses)
            .WithOne(o => o.MainClass)
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.MainClassId);

        // Configure self-referencing LatestOtherClass as an optional relationship
        modelBuilder.Entity<MainClass>()
            .HasOne(m => m.LatestOtherClass)
            .WithMany() // No navigation back to MainClass from this side
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.LatestOtherClassId)
            .IsRequired(false);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}


Thank you, I was halfway there with a shadow property on my main class but not the other class. This is looking much better now.

You are mostly welcome.

What is LatestOtherClassId populated with here? Is it clearly defined, genuinely asking. Seems reliant on the EF Core implementation.
